# Can't compile Kernel module with KBUILD_CFLAGS_MODULE

Tags: linux-kernel, compiling, kernel-modules

I'm having trouble to compile kernel modules with `KBUILD_CFLAGS_MODULE` with new kernel. The compiler shows me a weird error. Such builds used to work with my older kernel (5.5) but does not work anymore with my 5.16 kernel.

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

Dummy module:

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
static int __init lkm_example_init(void) {return 0;}
static void __exit lkm_example_exit(void){}
module_init(lkm_example_init);
module_exit(lkm_example_exit);
```

Makefile:

```
TARGET ?= test
obj-m += ${TARGET}.o
KBUILD_CFLAGS_MODULE := "-O1" "-mcmodel=medium" # Examples
.PHONY: all
all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

If I comment out the `KBUILD_CFLAGS_MODULE` line, my build work.

However, if uncommented my compilation fails with this error message:

```
make TARGET=test 
make -C /lib/modules/5.16.0/build M=/home/user/test modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/user/linux'
  CC [M]  /home/user/test/test.o
In file included from ./include/linux/module.h:22,
                 from /home/user/test/test.c:2:
./include/linux/module.h:183:39: error: expected ',' or ';' before 'KBUILD_MODFILE'
  183 | #define MODULE_FILE MODULE_INFO(file, KBUILD_MODFILE);
      |                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/moduleparam.h:26:47: note: in definition of macro '__MODULE_INFO'
   26 |   = __MODULE_INFO_PREFIX __stringify(tag) "=" info
      |                                               ^~~~
./include/linux/module.h:183:21: note: in expansion of macro 'MODULE_INFO'
  183 | #define MODULE_FILE MODULE_INFO(file, KBUILD_MODFILE);
      |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/module.h:230:34: note: in expansion of macro 'MODULE_FILE'
  230 | #define MODULE_LICENSE(_license) MODULE_FILE MODULE_INFO(license, _license)
      |                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~
/home/user/test/test.c:4:1: note: in expansion of macro 'MODULE_LICENSE'
    4 | MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:287: /home/user/test/test.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1846: /home/user/test] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/linux'
make: *** [Makefile:6: all] Error 2
```

Do you know what could be the root cause of this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not obvious from the documentation, but you’re supposed to *add* to `KBUILD_CFLAGS_MODULE`. Change your declaration to

```
KBUILD_CFLAGS_MODULE += "-O1" "-mcmodel=medium" # Examples
```

and the build will work.

The root cause of the build failure is that `KBUILD_CFLAGS_MODULE` lost its initial `-DMODULE` contents, which messed up [the `MODULE_FILE` declaration](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.16.14/source/include/linux/module.h#L181).